# Remove border on pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm drawing a graph with pgfplot. The values aren't important, I just want to show the shape of the function and so I don't want a border around my graph.

I can't find how to remove/change the color of the border, is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use axis lines key either for every axis or specifically for one axis. See the [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) manual.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=none]
\addplot[blue,samples=40]{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
\begin{axis}[
        hide x axis,
        hide y axis]
```

As [Manuel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21930/manuel) said in a comment, the following would also work

```
\begin{axis}[hide axis]
```

Comment: I think `hide axis` works, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Manuel I have just tested and you are right, it does work. Perhaps you should post it as a third answer for the record? I will certainly vote it up!

Comment: No, it's (almost) exactly the same as yours, you just forget it. Edit your answer.